# How to output filtered objects to the MongoDB console

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have objects with categories in which their cost and date of addition lie. Each user has such categories. I need to display all categories for the month "08" in the console. How can i do this? Now my code displays the entire object with the user. And I need categories for "08" month.

```js
mongoClient.connect(function (err, client) {
  const db = client.db("expensesdb");
  const collection = db.collection("users");

  if (err) return console.log(err);

  collection
    .find({
      name: "Tom",
    })
    .toArray(function (err, results) {
      console.log(results);
      client.close();
    });
});
```

```js
сategories: {
  products: {
    cost: "50$",
    date: {
      day: `13`,
      month: `08`,
      year: `2022`,
    },
  },
  health: {
    cost: "550$",
    date: {
      day: `13`,
      month: `08`,
      year: `2022`,
    },
  },
  entertainment: {
    cost: "100$",
    date: {
      day: `16`,
      month: `05`,
      year: `2022`,
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your data structure, you're using documents with dynamic keys, meaning that `categories` object will contain keys which we can't know since they could be anything `products`, `drink`, anything.

I would first change the structure to be more like this:

```
categories: [
    {
       name: "products",
       cost: "50$",
       date: {
       day: `13`,
       month: `08`,
       year: `2022`,
    }, 
]
```

Second, if you're going to query categories a lot, I prefer having them in their own collection and querying that collection instead of `users` collection like this:

```
mongoClient.connect(function (err, client) {
  // this should be done first 
  if (err){
     console.log(err); // better use a logging library instead of console.log
     // you log the error and then you return
     return;
  }
  const db = client.db("expensesdb");
  const collection = db.collection("categories");

  

  collection
    .find({
      date: {month: "08"},
    })
    .toArray(function (err, results) {
      console.log(results);
      client.close();
    });
});
```

But since I hate callback style and prefer `async/await` I would do this:

```
try{
   const client = await mongoClient.connect();
   const db = client.db("expensesdb");
   const collection = db.collection("categories");
   const categories = (await collection.find({date: {month: "08"}})).toArray(); // the result of await is a Cursor so toArray is called on the result of find not on the promise returned by find.
}catch(err){
   console.log(err); // again, better use a logging library
}
```

You can wrap the above code in `async function someNameYouChoose` and call that function anywhere, even in index.js. my advice use `async/await` or at least `Promise`s from now on, if you're using callbacks for some performance reason this is no longer a reason because `Promise`s performance has improved with newer NodeJS versions.

How you connect `users` collection with `categories` collection is up to you, you can just duplicate data between them and synchronize them in your code on insert/update/delete, or you can have an ID reference from category to user or categories array of ID reference.

### EDIT

if you need to return categories of only one specific user (maybe the current logged-in user) then you can filter on the result of MongoDB query from NodeJS code like this:

```
try {
  const client = await mongoClient.connect();
  const db = client.db("expensesdb");
  const collection = db.collection("users");
  const user = await collection.findOne({
    user: userId /* userId should come from user's request, like a path param for example */,
  });
  return {
    ...user,
    categories: user.categories.filter(
      (category) => category.date.month === "08"
    ),
  };
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err); // again, better use a logging library
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your proposed data structure actually seemed better to me. But now it doesn't look for your find(). I get "[]" in the console

Comment: Can you tell me the output of fetching all categories without any filtering? @rickray

Comment: I used your category structure. And after I searched for .find({date:{month: "08"}, }) an empty array "[ ]" was displayed in the console

Comment: When I exit the entire document with the user, then I have the following document structure: {
name: "Tom"
'categories': [ [Array] ]
}

Comment: I'm not talking about users collection, I'm talking about categories collection, you don't need to filter users collection if all you need is to return categories (unless you need to return both info, maybe you can tell me then what fields should be returned) @rickray

Comment: @rickray so give me `db.categories.find({})` from MongoDB console not NodeJS console (called mongosh or mongo depending on MongoDB Version you're using)

Comment: I have a collection of users in which documents (users) lie. In one document, a field with the username and an array with the categories in which it is returned. I want to display by date in category console.Is it possible to do this with such a structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247256/discussion-between-niceman-and-rick-ray).